# How does postMessage know the targetOrigin and recipient's window origin

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I have a requirement in my project where I need to announce my readiness (to receive a message) to other domain by using `window.postMessage` system.

However I do not know who the calling domain would be but I have a list of allowed origins.

As of now I am looping through all my allowed origins array and posting readiness to all my allowed domains. This works fine but I see the below error in my console for all domains except the one for which the message was meant to be:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://www.example.com') does not match the recipient window's origin

I need a way with which I can identify with whom I am communicating so that I send `postMessage` only to that domain. I cannot use event object in window.receiveMessage because the communication has not started yet. I am still in the stage where I am just announcing my readiness.

Can somebody tell how window.postMessage gets to know about the `origin` and if I can use same parameter in my logic, or is there some other better way to implement this?

Regards,
Hakim

Comment: One option if you don't know would be to post to the opener with _targetOrigin_ `*`, then let the opener post back it's origin, check against your whitelist and if everything is good, continue from there

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. As of now i have implemented a workaround of query string. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any security concern in passing to your child iframe your origin via query string?